# How to install KVM on Windows server 2008 R2

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I run the following `powershell` command, i get an error.

Command is:

`@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/master/kvminstall.ps1'))"`

and the error is:

`Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure
channel."
At line:1 char:1
+ iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.co ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException`

Same command works okay on Windows 10.

Comment: did you check your proxy settings ? did you try to download the kvminstall.ps1 manualy ?

Comment: (1) Make sure you have Powershell 4 installed. (2) Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the server. I get an error when I open `https://raw.githubusercontent.com` this in IE 11. It is an ssl handshake issue.

Comment: You may manually clone or download kvm from [asp.net home repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Home)